# A word for "dating", "game", "seduction"

Tags: word, slang

I'm trying to learn some new words and it came to my mind this word we use in English "game", not like videogames or games to have fun but this "game" that involves talking to girls, approaching in the street, etc.

I've searched in Google, other forums, tried to translate different synonyms in pleco but I couldn't find a word with this precise meaning, maybe it is a slang word?

Does any word in mandarin with this meaning come to your head? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've encountered "pua" (= "pick up artist") used in Chinese, like [this](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/97178547).

Comment: "... that involves talking to girls, approaching in the street..." ---  搭讪, -- Dā shàn

Comment: [link] (https://www.no1pua.com/%E6%88%80%E6%84%9B%E9%A1%A7%E5%95%8F%E5%B7%A5%E4%BD%9C%E5%AE%A4fred%E7%95%B6%E9%81%B8%E4%BA%9E%E6%B4%B2%E5%8D%81%E5%A4%A7pua-top-10-asian-pick-up-artists-to-watch-out-for-fred-pua/)  一種社會行為--調情--

Comment: 玩家 as player in Hong Kong,  from a Cantonese counseling youtube program

Answer (score 2):

A short and informal verb: 泡 (e.g. 泡妞)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes we use "勾搭" as a verb.

Answer (score 1):

"...this "game" involves talking to girls, approaching in the street, etc."

"搭讪" - simply walk up to a girl to initiate a conversation in the hope to strike out a friendship/relationship.

"調戲"(吃豆腐) - teasing a girl with seductive language and/or touching for personal fun.

"勾搭" or "勾引" - seduce a girl or a woman for personal pleasure, usually sexually orientated.

"

Answer (score 1):

泡 for 泡妞

撩 for 撩妹

勾搭 for 勾搭妹子/勾搭美女/勾搭小妹